# main menu in one row then sub menu in another horizontal row in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am using word press. actually i want menu plugin for main menu menu in one row then the sub menus in another row. any one know which menu plugin is used for that scenario?
Menu:
[image]

Comment: Exactly what you want..

Comment: i want menu same like above picture...

Answer (score 0):

I think that [UberMenu](http://wpmegamenu.com/) is what you need. It is a user friendly customizable menu, but it is not free unfortunately.

**[EDIT]**

Or you can try [WordPress jQuery Mega Menu Plugin](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/demo-wordpress-jquery-mega-menu-plugin/), this one is free and great for a custom menu.